# DelegatedType Inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two nearly identical models, except one has three or four extra attributes.

I didn't want to use Single Table Inheritance (STI) because instances of model A will have a bunch of nil values that only pertain to model B.

I didn't want to use abstract classes because I can't query across both, and the shared fields are duplicated in each table.

So I thought maybe Delegated Types introduced in rails 6.1 would be a good fit for this.  So here is my contrived example:

> `Automobile` holds all the shared fields, `LuxuryAutomobile` has some extra attributes that only pertain to it.

**Migrations:**

```
  create_table "automobiles" do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "num_wheels"
    t.integer "num_doors"
    t.string "color"
    t.string "autoable_type"
    t.integer "autoable_id"
    t.references :autoable, polymorphic: true
  end

  create_table "luxury_automobiles" do |t|
    t.boolean "leather_seats"
    t.integer "num_screens"
    t.string "custom_monogram"
  end

  create_table "users" do |t|
    t.string "name"
  end
```

**automobile.rb**

```
class Automobile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  delegated_type :autoable, types: %w[ Automobile LuxuryAutomobile ]
  include Autoable
end
```

**luxury_automobile.rb**

```
class LuxuryAutomobile < ApplicationRecord
  include Autoable
  delegate :num_wheels, to: :automobile
end
```

**autoable.rb**

```
module Autoable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    has_one :automobile, as: :autoable, touch: true
  end
end
```

So it's pretty close!  I can create `Automobiles` and `LuxuryAutomobiles`

```
u = User.first
Automobile.create! autoable: LuxuryAutomobile.new(custom_monogram: "BMW"), user: u, num_wheels: 6
```

So I can then call:

```
la = LuxuryAutomobile.last

la.automobile.num_wheels #returns 6
```

I can shorten that call further by using `delegate` in `luxury_automobile.rb`

```
delegate :num_wheels, to: :automobile
```

and in the console:

```
la = LuxuryAutomobile.last

la.num_wheels #returns: 6
la.custom_monogram #returns: "BMW"
```

**Is there a more seamless way to do this?**  I feel like it's 90% there, but I can't *assign* attributes like `num_wheels` to a `LuxuryAutomobile`.  It would be great if missing attributes from `LuxuryAutomobile` looked up the chain acted as one with `Automobile`.

```
la = LuxuryAutomobile.last
la.num_wheels #returns: 6
la.custom_monogram #returns: "BMW"

la.num_wheels = 8 #NoMethodError (undefined method `num_wheels=' for #<LuxuryAutomobile:0x00007fa1e70fe750>)
```

Comment: It's telling you what the solution is there. Use `def num_wheels=(val)` in your LuxuryAutomobile model and set the value on the Automobile manually. It's not the prettiest solution, but it will work. Not submitting this as an answer, cause there is more than likely a better option, but this should get you rolling (heh) quickly.

Comment: You could even consider to add these getter & setter methods dynamically in the Autoable module, by looping over the table attributes from Automobile. This way each other Model that gets this module included, will get access to these.

Comment: ps. I think you shouldn't include the module in the Automobile class itself, otherwise it will create a strange has_one to itself, or is that your intention?

Comment: I'm not actually sure.  It's a good point, but I'm not sure of the ramifications yet, I guess I have to do some testing.  I haven't actually seen DelegatedType work like this, usually it will be something like `Entry` and subclasses like `Message` and `Comment`.  I will try it without